# Fast method to read csv with UTF-16LE encoding

Tags: r, utf-16le

I'm dealing with .csv files with UTF-16LE encoding, this method works to read the files, but read.csv is very slow compared to read_csv.

```
  read.csv2(path,dec=",",skip=1,header=T,fileEncoding="UTF-16LE",sep="/t")
```

Unfortunately I can't make read_csv work, I only get empty rows and I don't find a way to even specify encoding in the function.

I can't share my data, but if anyone dealt with this encoding any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify file encodings with readr functions like read_csv with the locale option: `locale=locale(encoding="UTF-16LE")`.  However, I haven't successfully read in a utf-16le file with read_csv.  I get an "Incomplete multibyte sequence" error.  There's a related [issue filed](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/306), but I still have issues with my file -- hopefully others will have more success.