# read into R data frame from cognos 8 file (utf 16) with readr

Tags: r, csv, readr, cognos-8, utf-16le

I am attempting to read csv files generated by cognos 8 into r using readr.

Example file attached for reproducibility: [Example csv file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhzqEf3vXnLPvXkDyTw0-_DtZ7zk)

The following python code works:

```
df = pd.read_table('csv_test.csv', encoding = 'utf-16')
```

I've tried the following in R, and none of them return the correct result. They either error (Incomplete multibyte sequence) or read in improperly (as nested lists or similar)

```
csv_data <- read_table('csv_test.csv')
csv_data <- read_table('csv_test.csv', locale = locale(encoding = 'UTF-16LE'))
csv_data <- read_tsv('csv_test.csv')
csv_data <- read_tsv('csv_test.csv', locale = locale(encoding = 'UTF-16LE'))
```

I used `guess_encoding()` to get the UTF-16LE, I also tried UTF-16.

Comment: There's this [open issue for the readr package](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/306).

Comment: And while there's not a good solution there, [suggested duplicate: Fast method to read csv with UTF-16LE encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36862340/903061)

Comment: Thank you @gregor . I tried the base read.csv file but didn't get that to work. Read_delim as shown in the open github issue will work for now.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comment by Gregor, there is an open issue with the readr package for this.

As a workaround, base package read_delim will work:

```
csv_data <- read.delim('csv_test.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = 'UTF-16LE')
```